# Copy file from remote computer to local computer within an Invoke-command session in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I use a pwsh code to connect to a remote computer to generate a CSV file.

1. I do this by Invoke-command, the code works perfectly, generates a CSV file on the server.
2. The name of the CSV file is generated dynamically.

**However, I'm unable to copy that file from the remote computer to local computer.**

Is there a way to use  copy-item within Invoke-command?

## Please advise/guide.

The snippet of the code is given below.

---

```
#   Target Server
$TargetServer = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

#   Capture the VM credentials
$creds = Get-Credential -Title "Enter admin Password" -UserName admin

#   Create session
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential $creds

$scriptBlock = {
    #   Attempt Install
    Install-Module -Name Join-Object

    #   Attempt Import
    Import-Module -Name Join-Object 

    #   IP Address
    $ipAdress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPV4).IPAddress[0]

    #   Set the CSV file name
    $lastLogonReportName = "LastLogonReport__" + $ipAdress + "__" + (get-date -Format "dd MMM yyyy_dddd") + ".csv"

    ... ...
    ... ...
    ... ...
    ... ...

    $Output

    #   Set Location to user's Downloads folder
    Set-Location -Path $HOME\Downloads
    
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path ./$lastLogonReportName

    # Copy-Item $lastLogonReportName -Destination "D:\" -FromSession $Session
 }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use `Copy-Item` for this, but there is an easier way:

```
#   Create session
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential $creds

$scriptBlock = {
    #   Set the CSV file name
    $date = Get-Date -Format "dd MMM yyyy"

    #   IP Address
    $ipAdress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPV4).IPAddress[0]

    $lastLogonReportName = "LastLogonReport__${ipAdress}__$date.csv"

    #   Destination
    $destination = Join-Path "$HOME\Downloads" -ChildPath $lastLogonReportName
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path $destination -NoTypeInformation
    $Output # => Send this Object to be captured on locahost
}

$params = @{
    Session = $session
    ScriptBlock = $scriptBlock
}

$captureThisObject = Invoke-Command @params

PS /> $captureThisObject # => Is your CSV on localhost
```

If you wanted to use `Copy-Item` instead, have `Invoke-Command` return the path where the CSV was stored on the host and then (from outside the invocation) you call `Copy-Item -FromSession`:

```
#   Create session
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential $creds

$scriptBlock = {
    #   Set the CSV file name
    $date = Get-Date -Format "dd MMM yyyy"

    #   IP Address
    $ipAdress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPV4).IPAddress[0]

    $lastLogonReportName = "LastLogonReport__${ipAdress}__$date.csv"

    #   Destination
    $destination = Join-Path "$HOME\Downloads" -ChildPath $lastLogonReportName
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path $destination -NoTypeInformation
    
    $destination # => Send this Path to be captured on locahost
}

$params = @{
    Session = $session
    ScriptBlock = $scriptBlock
}

$remotePath = Invoke-Command @params
Copy-Item -Path $remotePath -Destination path/to/csvHere.csv -FromSession $session
```

Comment: My bad, I was quick enough to delete my comment. Thanks for the guidance. 

However, now I'm stuck with a different issue: 
`Export-Csv: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\'.`

Comment: @Gagan don't use relative paths for your export, note how I'm using the `Join-Path` call to get the absolute path were the file will be stored.

Comment: I'm using the same code that you've used. Literally copy-pasted.

Comment: @Gagan mmm I've updated my answer, I noticed I didn't included the `$IPAddress` part. Tho I don't think that's causing the issue. Where do you see the CSV getting stored on the remote host? It should be something like `C:\Users\admin\Downloads\LastLogonReport__10.10.10.10__13 Dec 2021.csv`

Comment: Thanks @santiago, the code is now working. I had to use `$Using:[variable]` to get the `$logonReportName` correctly. 

However, thank you so much!

Comment: @Gagan no problem! i'm not sure how that could work, would you like to edit your question with what you're doing